# k/Column number in Perl

Tags: perl

So I'm sure this is somewhere on the site, but as *always*, I have looked high and low before asking a question.

In Bash, you can use certain flags on some commands (such as `k[number]` on `sort`) to grab a certain column from a text file. What is the method for doing this in Perl? For an example from my input file:

```
Jess 6 8 25000
```

Say that I want to run a statement

```
if (k2 =< 6)
{
   print "foo";
}
```

Of course, k2 doesn't work in Perl. May someone show me (or link me to) how this is done?

Comment: I'm not aware of any flags like that in Perl. Probably have to `split` the read line, and then take the right element from the resulting array. Except if it's a one-liner from command line, then you can use the option `-a`.

Comment: Are you looking for a script or a one-liner?

Comment: @AntonH Sorry yeah good question. I'm making a whole script. The columns after the name are skills. If the skills reach a certain threshold, the person will be "hired." The purpose of fetching information from the columns is to run tests after reading each line in, such as  `if (k2 > 5) then... else...` etc.

Comment: To my knowledge, there are no flags of the kind. Best is, if the line is in a scalar variable, like `$str`, you would have to split and capture that in an array, like so: `@myArray = split /\s+/, $str;`. Then access the elements like an ordinary array.

Comment: Or, in short, `while (<$fh>) { if (split)[1] > 5) { ... } }`.  Here `$fh` is the filehandle with which you opened the file, and `while` then iterates over lines, one at a time. The `[1]` selects the second field from the line, which `split` has split by whitespace. This assumes that you know for fact that _each_ line has that information in the second column. It doesn't deal with possibly empty lines, checking whether a line has the expected format, etc. So it will test the second field on every line (second "column") for whether it's larger than 5.  Is this what you need?

Comment: @zdim Thank you this is helpful. It's late here so I will try this tomorrow morning. I'm curious, though, does split delimit on whitespace by default? or do I have to do some funky /\s/ syntax?

Comment: The default for [split](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html) is -- `split ' ', $_`, where `' '` means any amount of any whitespace and [$_ variable](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#General-Variables) is default for many things. For one, it is the line currently processed by `while <$fh>`.  So all you should need is `split;`, which returns the list. Then you take an element, say the second one by `(split)[1]`. Try it out and if there are problems edit the question so ask about them.

Comment: The code I posted in my previous comment should be `if ((split)[1] > 5)` (one more parenthesis)

Comment: @AntonH: If you're writing  `split /\s+/` then you almost certainly want `split ' '` instead

Comment: The `-a` flag automatically splits the input and allow you to access the column through `@F` array (I let you look it up). However, it's conveninient for one liners (or very small scripts), but I don't recommend using it in a full script.

Comment: @zdim thank you. I used your suggestion and it works perfectly.

Comment: @javacplusplus  Great! You did it yourself :) Thank you for feedback :)

Comment: Can you please write up your solution as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will check the second column:

```
(split)[1]
```

Sample script:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
my $filename = 'input';
open(FILE, $filename) or die "Can not open $filename.";

print "\n";
while(<FILE>)
{
        #The test
        if ((split)[1] < 10)
        {
                print "The second column is less than ten\n";
        }
        elsif ((split)[1] > 10)
        {
                print "The second column is more than ten\n";
        }
        else
        {
                print "The second column is equal to ten\n";
        }
}
```

Input:

```
#Input file
0 5 0
0 10 0
0 15 0
0 20 0
0 1 0
0 10 0
```

Output:

```
The second column is less than ten
The second column is equal to ten
The second column is more than ten
The second column is more than ten
The second column is less than ten
The second column is equal to ten
```

Comment: Better late than never, I guess. Hopefully this can be of use to future readers.

Answer (score 2):

You can try with the command line Perl as well

with the inputs

```
$ cat reubens.txt
0 5 0
0 10 0
0 15 0
0 20 0
0 1 0
0 10 0

$  perl -lane ' print  "The second column is ", $F[1] < 10 ? "less than 10": $F[1]==10 ? "equal to 10" : "more than 10"  '  reubens.txt
The second column is less than 10
The second column is equal to 10
The second column is more than 10
The second column is more than 10
The second column is less than 10
The second column is equal to 10

$
```

Answer (score 1):

In case you want to do it for exactly one column and want to avoid maintaining the result of "split" in array shape. (Otherwise use split as mentioned in the comments.)

```
perl -ne"/(?:\w+\s+){1}(\w+\b)/;print $1.\"\n\""
```

Will print the column of word-like characters between space-like characters, identified by the number inside "{}", in this case "1"; counting columns starting with 0.
E.g. it prints "6" for the input example, using "1".

How:
Make a regular expression for a column followed by space,

```
(?:\w+\s+)
```

require it a number of times,

```
{1}
```

then grab a regular expression for a colum followed by anything not word-like (including end of line)

```
(\w+\b)
```

The desired column is found in the grabbed string

```
$1
```

I did this in a command line one liner which expects standard input, to be able to test it.
Please just adapt it into your script.